# JAXB Unmarsharller: XMLAttributes are mapped, but its XmlElements are not

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

**TL;DR:** When I unmarshall from XML to POJO I only have the XmlAttributes well mapped, however all XmlElement are null.

Hi there!

I have the following problem. This class was generated with JAXB

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "activity"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "activityDetails", namespace = "http://lorem.ipsum.com/")
public class ActivityDetails {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Activity activity;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "schemaVersion", required = true)
    protected float schemaVersion;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "actionType")
    protected ActionTypes actionType;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp;
```

This is an example XML

```
<activityDetails 
    actionType="CREATE" 
    schemaVersion="2.0" 
    timestamp="2020-01-02T15:31:50.549Z" 
    xmlns="http://lorem.ipsum.com/">
    <activity>
        <activityId>
            <start>2020-01-01T03:00:00Z</start>
            <end>2020-01-02T02:59:00Z</end>
        </activityId>
    </activity>
</activityDetails>
```

But, when this code is executed (please don't judge me, it's legacy code):

```
    Object xmlClass = Class.forName("com.lorem.ipsum." + className).getConstructor().newInstance();
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(xmlClass.getClass());
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(element));
```

The result "object" have all XmlAttribute well mapped, but no one of their XmlElement
[image: IntelliJ Debug]

PS: The namespace in the generated class was added manually, if I don't do that I have this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://lorem.ipsum.com/", local:"activityDetails"). Expected elements are <{}activityDetails>
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:** If I set all `@XmlElement` the namespace property I finally map the elements, but I must intervene all the classes. Is there another way to achieve that without having to modify all the fields of all the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found this solution: Instead of putting the namespace in each of the XMLElements I put the following `package-info.java` in the package of the generated classes.

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    namespace="http://lorem.ipsum.com/",
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://lorem.ipsum.com/")})
package com.lorem.ipsum.generated;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem, but for the default namespace I get an extra namespace. FOr eg: The XML file has <Registry></Registry> as the root tag and it is present in xmlns namespace. With the package-info modification, I expect it to come out after unmarshalling and marshalling as <Registry></Registry>. But I get <ns3:Registry xmlns:ns3="http://www.registar.com">.. An extra namespace. My prefix inside package-info seems like of no influence

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

I guess I am able to figure out the issue. This is happening because you have not provided any prefix to your namespace in XML. Following code would work for your provided sample XML:

XML:

```
<activityDetails
        actionType="CREATE"
        schemaVersion="2.0"
        timestamp="2020-01-02T15:31:50.549Z"
        xmlns:ns0="http://lorem.ipsum.com/">
    <activity>
        <activityId>
            <start>2020-01-01T03:00:00Z</start>
            <end>2020-01-02T02:59:00Z</end>
        </activityId>
    </activity>
</activityDetails>
```

ActivityDetails.class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "activityDetails", namespace = "http://lorem.ipsum.com/")
public class ActivityDetails {
    private Activity activity;

    @XmlAttribute
    private float schemaVersion;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String actionType;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String timestamp;
}
```

Activity.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Activity {
    private ActivityID activityId;
}
```

ActivityID.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ActivityID {
    private String start;
    private String end;
}
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("activity.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(ActivityDetails.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final ActivityDetails activityDetails = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, ActivityDetails.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(activityDetails.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(ActivityDetails.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(activityDetails, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is your output:

```
ActivityDetails(activity=Activity(activityId=ActivityID(start=2020-01-01T03:00:00Z, end=2020-01-02T02:59:00Z)), schemaVersion=2.0, actionType=CREATE, timestamp=2020-01-02T15:31:50.549Z)
<ns0:activityDetails xmlns:ns0="http://lorem.ipsum.com/" schemaVersion="2.0" actionType="CREATE" timestamp="2020-01-02T15:31:50.549Z">
   <activity>
      <activityId>
         <start>2020-01-01T03:00:00Z</start>
         <end>2020-01-02T02:59:00Z</end>
      </activityId>
   </activity>
</ns0:activityDetails>
```

Comment: Thanks... Batman? Hehehe. The thing is I can't modify the XML (This code is part of a Apache Beam Dataflow) So I have to deal with the XML without prefix :(